# consistent set question

Tags: first-order-logic

Ive encountered the following question (question of true \ false):

For every consistent set (but not maximally consistent) of propositions $\Phi$ exists consistent set (but not maximally consistent) of propositions $\Phi'$ such that: $\Phi \subseteq \Phi'$

This claim is false, but i really don't understand why, it seems reasonable that if there is some consistent set $\Phi$ but not maximal consistent, so there is a claim that says that there exists a module for $\Phi$, and because the condition of not being maximum consistent i can conclude there is at least 2 modules, lets assume $\varphi \in \Phi$,

then if we define $\Phi' = \Phi\cup \left\{  \neg\neg\varphi\right\}$, so $\Phi\subseteq \Phi'$, and we can imply this 'trick' for every consistent set.

where am i wrong?

Comment: Do you mean $\subset$ or $\subseteq$? By "modules" do you mean models? What's your definition of maximally consistent?

Comment: If $\Phi$ is a consistent set but not maximally consistent, then $\Phi$ is a consistent set but not maximally consistent such that $\Phi \subseteq \Phi$.